# Use an Array of Abbreviations to Extract Properties for New Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have an object that contains property names that indicate the start and end times of a schedule for each day of the week. I also have an array containing only the day abbreviations.

Based on this array, I want to convert this object so that it looks like what's in the section labeled "Expected Output" below:

```
var options=["sun","mon","tues","wed"];
var items = {
  sun_start: "10:30",
  sun_end: "11:00",
  mon_start: "",
  mon_end: ""
}
```

Expected Output:

```
 {
  "sun": "10:30,11:00",
  "mon": "",
  "tues": "",
  "wed": ""
 }
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried on some fiddle

Comment: What should happen if only `item.sun_start` is defined and not `item.sun_end`? Or vice versa?

Comment: @trincot, should be empty string i.e `"sun": ""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```js
var options=["sun","mon","tues","wed"];
var items = {
  sun_start: "10:30",
  sun_end: "11:00",
  mon_start: "",
  mon_end: ""
}

function getStartEndString(dayAbbreviation)
{
  let startTime = ""
  let endTime = "";
  if (items.hasOwnProperty(dayAbbreviation+"_start"))
  {
    startTime = items[dayAbbreviation+"_start"];
  }
  if (items.hasOwnProperty(dayAbbreviation+"_end"))
  {
    endTime = items[dayAbbreviation+"_end"];
  }
  if(startTime.length > 0 && endTime.length > 0)
  {
    return `${startTime},${endTime}`;
  }
  else
  {
    return "";
  }
}

let obj = {};
options.forEach((dayAbbreviation)=>
{
  obj[dayAbbreviation] = getStartEndString(dayAbbreviation);
});
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet will give what you need.

```
var result = {};
options.forEach((option) => {
    var item_keys = Object.keys(items).filter(key => (key.indexOf(option) != -1));
    var val = '';
    item_keys.forEach(key => (val = val ? (val+','+items[key]) : items[key]));
    result[option] = val;
});
```

Comment: To add more value to your answer consider adding an explanation on what this code does

Comment: This answer does not cover the case when `_end` keys are before `_start` in the items. `var items = {
  sun_end: "12:30",
  sun_start: "11:00",
  mon_start: "",
  mon_end: ""
};` will result in `{sun: "12:30,11:00", mon: "", tues: "", wed: ""}`